# get a code that Return True if in an array there is two 3 next to each-other?

Tags: python

```
#here is the code                                     
def has_33(nums):                                        
    for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):                  
        if nums[i:i+2]==[3,3]:
            return True
    return False
nums = [1,2,3,3]
print(has_33(nums))
```

questions:

1. why the code used `len(nums)-1` in second line?(why used -1 ?)
2. in the 3rd line why do they used `[i:i+2]==[3,3]` and how does this code perform ?

please let me know ,
i am basically a noob in coding right now please help me to under stand how this code works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: We use `len(nums) - 1` to avoid iterating on the last element of the array `nums`.  The expression `nums[i:i+2]` takes a slice of the array `nums`, restricted to indices `i` and `i+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you're looking for two elements in a row, there's no point in checking the last element of the list, since there's nothing after it. So the loop stops at the 2nd-to-last index.
2. `nums[i:i+2]` returns a slice of the list from element `i` to element `i+1`. Those are 2 consecutive elements. Then it compares this to `[3, 3]` to see if that pair of elements are two 3's next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because a list of the length n has only n-1 pairs (for example, [1,2,3,4] has [1,2], [2,3] and [3,4])
2. Beacuse list[x:y] does not return element y of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is simple and should work for what you want to do.

```
a=[0, 1, 2, 0, 3]

def has_33():
    last_i = 0
    for i in a:
        if last_i==3 and i==3:
            return True
        if i==3:
            last_i = 3
    return False

print(has_33())
```

Also works in different combinations of ...3,3...